# Why are duplicate implementations of templates generated when the type info is not used?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Consider:

```cpp
void* global_ptr;

template<typename T>
void set_global_ptr(T* ptr)
{
    global_ptr = ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int foo = 123;
    float bar = 456;
    set_global_ptr(&foo);
    set_global_ptr(&bar);
    return 0;
}
```

On gcc 8.1 with flags `-O3 -fno-inline` this gets compiled to:

```
void set_global_ptr<int>(int*):
  mov QWORD PTR global_ptr[rip], rdi
  ret
void set_global_ptr<float>(float*):
  mov QWORD PTR global_ptr[rip], rdi
  ret
main:
  sub rsp, 24
  lea rdi, [rsp+8]
  mov DWORD PTR [rsp+8], 123
  mov DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 0x43e40000
  call void set_global_ptr<int>(int*)
  lea rdi, [rsp+12]
  call void set_global_ptr<float>(float*)
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 24
  ret
global_ptr:
  .zero 8
```

Clang 6.0 produces something similar. I disabled inlining, otherwise no functions get generated at all.

It would make sense that if the type is not used, or gets type-erased, only one implementation should be generated. However I can see that two identical implementations of `set_global_ptr` were generated. Why is that?

I used [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) to produce the assembly.

Comment: I have a hunch that the reason is along the lines of "standard says so". As in: Standard specifies, that the code should be generated for every different type, that is used with the template, regardless if the type information was used, or not. But that is a hunch, and I would need to double check it against C++ standard, to be certain.

Comment: Do you expect that `&set_global_ptr<int>` == `&set_global_ptr<float>` (with correct erased-type casting)?

Comment: Have you tried making the functions `static`? Point is, that without it, you need two symbols, so two functions are generated. Why isn't that optimized away post-hoc, you may ask. The answer to that is possibly that there is no use case that prompted anyone to write one.

Comment: MSVC *does* merge identical functions and has been criticized for *that*. If you use the function address in a map, you might get only one entry when you wanted two.

Comment: @Jarod42 That is actually a very good point. I can imagine that there may be situations where it could lead to confusion and bugs, were that the case.

Comment: "_I disabled inlining, otherwise no functions get generated at all._" There's your answer: why optimize something that will be optimized away anyway?